# Interesting Successive differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Prove
$$\frac{d^{n}}{dx^n}(\frac{x^n}{1+x^2})=n!\sin(y)\{\sin(y)-\dbinom{n}{1}\cos(y)\sin(2y)+\dbinom{n}{2}\cos^2(y)\sin(3y)-....\}, x=\cot(y)$$

I tried to do it by induction I got 
$$\frac{d^{n}}{dx^n}(\frac{x^n}{1+x^2})=\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}(\frac{x.x^{n-1}}{1+x^2}))=x\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}(\frac{x^{n-1}}{1+x^2})+n\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n}}(\frac{x^{n-1}}{1+x^2})$$

But I am not getting the result anyone please help/

Can anyone please give me a complete solution

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: @KALPA I would advise against sounding pushy and impatient by adding later comments that are simply "please help."  Nothing sours a question like begging does.